# Authentication system generating a token which is already expired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, jwt

I am generating a token with express for my react app. Which is hosted is vercel. When I click in login button my express.js generate token and send it to frontend .

```
const loginEditorialController = async (req,res) =>{
    try{
        const db = getDb()
        const { email , password } = req.body

        if(!email || !password){
            return res.status(404).json({ 
                message : `No empty field allowed!`
            })
        }

        if (!/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email)) {
            return res.status(400).json({
              message: 'Invalid email format!',
            });
        }

        const query = { email : email }
        const user = await db.collection('editorial').findOne(query)
        
        if(!user){
            return res.status(403).json({
                message: 'Invaid email or password!',
                suggest : 'Please try again or create account.'
            })
        }

        if (!user.password) {
            return res.status(403).json({
                message: 'Invalid email or password!',
                suggest: 'Please try again or create an account.'
            });
        }

        const matched = await bcrypt.compare(password, user?.password)
        
        if(!matched){
            return res.status(403).json({ 
                message : 'Invalid email or password!',
            })
        }

        const jwt_user_data = {
            email:email,
            role: user.role
        }

        const access_token = jwt.sign({
            data: jwt_user_data
          }, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, 
          { expiresIn: '1h' }
        )

        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'User found!',
            additional : 'Login successfull',
            access_token
        })
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Which has a expiration time of 1 hour. In front end I have a hook that perform some operation based on time .But every time when I login the token got deleted just after setting up it in the local storage. I copied the token decoded it in their website . Found out the token is already expired . That's my condition become true and delete the token from local storage. I have faced the problem both in local check and after deployment. Here is my frontend code :

```
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useUserdata = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [u_email, setU_email] = useState('');
    const [u_role, setU_role] = useState('');

    const checkLocalStorage = () => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
        setLoading(true)
        try {
            const decoded = jwtDecode(token);

            if (Date.now() >= decoded.exp * 1000) {
                localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
                setU_email('');
                setU_role('');
            } else {
                const { email, role } = decoded.data;
                setU_email(email);
                setU_role(role);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
            setU_email('');
            setU_role('');
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        checkLocalStorage();
    }, []);

    const forceCheckLocalStorage = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        checkLocalStorage();
    };

    return { loading, u_email, u_role, forceCheckLocalStorage, setU_email, setU_role };
};

export default useUserdata;
```

I have tried several ways but nothing works.
Sorry for my bad English skill. Thanks.